Reregistering Azure Virtual Desktop Session Host; EXPIRED_MACHINE_TOKEN
We have an Azure Virtual Desktop environment that consists of about 10 host pools, each with 100 session hosts. I know we can have more, but due to constraints outside of our control, we had to limit how many we deployed per host pool. But that's not the topic of this question.
We're running into an issue involving session hosts being unavailable due to an expired registration token. Specifically
WVD-Agent service is stopped: EXPIRED_MACHINE_TOKEN, This VM needs to be properly registered in order to participate in the deployment
Event ID: 3277

To be clear, the session hosts have each been registered to the host pool for approximately four months prior to this error appearing. It seems like registration is "expiring".
We are able to fix it by having a new registration key generated and manually applying it using the instructions found in an AVD troubleshooting KB. I'm working on a scripted method of applying the steps in the article.
The instructions in the KB say to set two Registry values then restart the RDAgentBootLoader service:
$newKey = '<RegistrationToken>'

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RDInfraAgent" -Name "IsRegistered" -Value "0" -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RDInfraAgent" -Name "RegistrationToken" -Value $newKey -Force

Restart-Service RDAgentBootLoader

One thing the instructions don't mention is that the existing session host has to be deleted from the host pool. If not, an error will be thrown saying a session host with the VM's name already exists.
This process isn't working. I can set the Registry values and restart the service, but it isn't registering the VM to the host pool. It seems like RDAgentBootLoader doesn't know to look in the Registry to check that the VM is registered or to pick up the registration key if it isn't. I've also tried running the RDAgentBootLoader installer hoping it will fulfill it's purpose to no effect.
I've found that the only way to complete the re-registration, is to reinstall RDAgent and provide the registration key in the text field when prompted. This will populate the RegistrationToken Registry entry seemingly in a way that the RDAgentBootLoader installer recognizes and the re-registration to the host pool completes.
This poses a problem, though. I want to be able to script this so we can use the new registration key across all of the session hosts at once and avoid doing it piecemeal as users report the issue. I can't do this using the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand because that relies on RDAgent.
If I uninstall the agent so I can reinstall it and pass the new key, the run command will be left in a transitional state (I don't recall where I read this; I'll provide a citation when I find it). This effectively means I can't connect again to complete the process of reinstalling the agent, passing the registration key as a parameter, or reinstalling the agent boot loader.
Is there something in the process that I need to do which isn't listed? Are those instructions outdated and no longer applicable? Is there a better way to push the new registration key and re-register the VM to the host pool?
